# django-notifications-hq: how to implement

Tags: django, notifications

I'm using the django-notifications-hq for my django practice project which is an online booking for salon clients. I'm quite new to django and hoping to learn much more.

How can I implement the notification so that my users/employee will be notified that a new booking was created.

Can you please give me some examples as the django-notifications-hq documentation is a little bit confusing for me.

Any pointers or examples are much appreciated.

Thank you.

**models.py**

```
class NewBooking(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile = models.CharField(validators=[contact_regex], max_length=17, blank=False)  # validators should be a list
    employee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='employeename', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    services = models.ForeignKey('ListofService', related_name='servicename', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, blank=False, null=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, blank=False, null=True)
    new = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name
```

When the above model(new booking) will be saved, I want that one or more of my users will be notified using the django-notification-hq.

This is the part that I'm a little bit confused though,

**Generating Notifications**

**Generating notifications is probably best done in a separate signal.**

> from django.db.models.signals import post_save from
>   notifications.signals import notify from myapp.models import MyModel
>
> def my_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
>       notify.send(instance, verb='was saved')
>
> post_save.connect(my_handler, sender=MyModel)

**To generate an notification anywhere in your code, simply import the notify signal and send it with your actor, recipient, and verb.**

> from notifications.signals import notify
>
> notify.send(user, recipient=user, verb='you reached level 10') The
>   complete syntax is.
>
> notify.send(actor, recipient, verb, action_object, target, level,
>   description, public, timestamp, **kwargs)

**Arguments:
actor: An object of any type. (Required) Note: Use sender instead of actor if you intend to use keyword arguments
recipient: A Group or a User QuerySet or a list of User. (Required)
verb: An string. (Required)
action_object: An object of any type. (Optional)
target: An object of any type. (Optional)
level: One of Notification.LEVELS ('success', 'info', 'warning', 'error') (default=info). (Optional)
description: An string. (Optional)
public: An boolean (default=True). (Optional)
timestamp: An tzinfo (default=timezone.now()). (Optional)**

Comment: You should show us what you've tried. Now your problem is not clear at all, please refer to [Ask] to learn how to ask a clear, reproducible, concise question. Also what do you mean by 'will be notified'? The django-notifications-hq allows you to create a notification object, and helps you to manage the notifications, but as noted in the docs: "Sending email to users has not been integrated into this library." So this has nothing to do with push notifications.

Comment: Apart from the above, the django-notifications-hq library is a nice lightweight plugin to manage little notifications to users, that you can display wherever you want on the site when your users are logged in. Just try it out, write some code and if you hit a particular issue, post a question here.